# resize shiny WellPanel to contents and place a close button

Tags: r, layout, shiny

I started learning shiny recently and I am toying around with wellPanels. I am trying to create a wellPanel which will be no larger than necessary to fit its contents. I've managed to get the following:

[image: wellPanel]

but have not found a way to eliminate the right-hand side extra space of the wellPanel. If possible, I would also like to place the "X" button on the top right corner of the wellPanel. Is there a way to do these? Thanks in advance!

Here is the working code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(column(width = 6, 
                  wellPanel(
                    fluidRow(
                      column(width = 3, textInput(inputId = "layer", label = "Layer name", placeholder = "Layer name")),
                      column(width = 3, numericInput(inputId = "att_point", label = "Attachment Point", value = 100)),
                      column(width = 3, numericInput(inputId = "capacity", label = "Capacity", value = 100)),
                      column(width = 3, actionButton(inputId = "rm_btn", label = "", icon = icon("times")))
                    )))))

shinyApp(ui, function(input,output){})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the widths something like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(column(width = 6, 
                  wellPanel(
                    fluidRow(
                      column(width = 4, textInput(inputId = "layer", label = "Layer name", placeholder = "Layer name")),
                      column(width = 4, numericInput(inputId = "att_point", label = "Attachment Point", value = 100)),
                      column(width = 3, numericInput(inputId = "capacity", label = "Capacity", value = 100)),
                      column(width = 1, actionButton(inputId = "rm_btn", label = "", icon = icon("times")))
                    )))))

shinyApp(ui, function(input,output){})
```

With this you get an output which looks like this:
[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping to keep the width of the inputs equal amongst them, but this is the next best thing :) I finally managed to get around it using a splitLayout and increasing slightly the width of the inputs. Do you have any idea how to move the close button to the very top-right corner of the wellPanel?

Comment: @linuxfever, you could use custom `css` to do that